# Integer validation in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, validation

I am studying C++ and after I learned about some functions of the library `cctype` like `isdigit` I decided to make a program that validates user input only to be an integer number. So input like `123as`, `:$` or `+.234` are invalid, however I decided to keep the plus or minus sign, i.e., input like `-24` or `+142` are valid. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool integer_valid(string s);
int get_integer();

int main()
{
    int number;

    number = get_integer();
    cout << "The integer number is:\t" << number << "\n" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool integer_valid(string s)
{
    int i, length_s;
    bool is_valid = true;

    length_s = s.length();

    if (length_s == 0)
        is_valid = false;
    else
    {
        if (length_s == 1)
        {
            if (!isdigit(s[0]))
                is_valid = false;           
        }
        else
        {
            if (s[0] == '+' || s[0] == '-' || isdigit(s[0]) != 0)
            {
                for (i = 1; i < length_s; i++)
                {
                    if (!isdigit(s[i]))
                        is_valid = false;
                }                               
            }
            else
                is_valid = false;
        }           
    }
    return is_valid;
}

int get_integer()
{
    int new_number;
    string number;
    bool is_valid;

    do {
        cout << "Enter an integer number:\t";
        getline(cin, number);
        cout << "\n";

        is_valid = integer_valid(number);

        if (is_valid == false)
            cout << "ERROR. The entered number must be an integer.\n" << endl;
    } while (is_valid == false);

    new_number = stoi(number);

    return new_number;
}
```

I'm aware that in general is a bad practice to use `using namespace std`, but since my program has less tan 100 lines of code I think it's really not a big issue here. Moreover, I wonder if there is another (simpler/faster) way to validate integer numbers?

**EDIT:** Answering to the comment made by Roland Illig, I would say yes. More exactly, any kind of integer should be valid, but as far as I know, `int` has a defined size, so if I want to valid long integers I should use the type `long long int` and also the function `stoll`, right?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `111111111111111111111111111111111` a valid integer to you?

Comment: @RolandIllig I've edited my question.

Comment: "I know doing X is something I shouldn't do but I'm doing it here because Y" is never a good excuse especially when you're still learning the language. Best practices are best practices for a reason. Using them builds good habits and good habits will take you a long way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using a `bool is_valid` results in a deeply nested code. You have 5 levels of nesting, with the core of algorithm being hidden at the deepest one. I recommend an early return: as soon as you determine that the string doesn't pass a criteria, `return false;` immediately.
- Testing for `length_s == 0` is redundant. In this case `s[0]` is `'\0'`, which is neither a digit nor a sign.
- Passing `std::string` as an argument makes a copy. Prefer passing a (constant) reference.
- Leaving the point of the exercise aside, the best way to validate a number is to just go ahead and directly call `std:stoi` with the second parameter, e.g.:

  ```
      size_t end;
      int number = std::stoi(s, &end);
      if (s[end] != '\0') {
          // The string was not parsed completely. It is not a number.
      }
  ```

Comment: Is testing the length really redundant? cppreference mentions that accessing `s[len]` on a non-const string invokes undefined behavior, so I'd rather be careful here.

Comment: @RolandIllig The question is tagged [tag:C++11], where it is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  For some reason in my classes we use C++ without mentioning its version. That's the reason why I don't know exactly which things are well defined which things aren't.

Answer (score 3):

### [Avoid `system("pause")`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/3964927)

It's a security risk, not portable, and introduces unnecessary overhead.

### Variables should use the proper types

The return type for [`std::string::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is `std::string::size_type` (which is usually an unsigned type), so that should be the type for `length_s`, not `int`.

Similarly, `i` should be of type `std::string::size_type` because:

1. you are comparing it to `length_s` on the line `for (i = 1; i < length_s; i++)`. The two variables should both be unsigned for proper comparison, and preferably the exact same type.
2. you are using it as the argument type for [`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), which uses `std::string::size_type` as the argument type.

### I would still avoid `using namespace std`

On Stack Overflow, I once saw an [even shorter program which failed to compile due to `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593548/3964927) -- the programmer attempted to define a function `int plus(int, int)` which conflicted with [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus). Your program may have less than 100 lines of code, but that just means there aren't too many instances in which you have to qualify a name with `std::`. Plus, it's best to get into the habit of not using `using namespace std` for when you write longer programs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why shouldn't I use the type `int` for the variable `i`? It's the counter.

Comment: @Xam You are comparing `i` to `length_s`, so they should both be unsigned. Your compiler should warn you about a signed/unsigned comparison if `i` is an `int` but `length_s` is `std::string::size_type`. I've updated my answer to explain this more fully.

Comment: @Null, compilation errors are not that evil as ADL jokes.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution one:**

You're already using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), did you know that it throws an exception if it can't convert to an `int`? It already does the validation for you, use it like:

```
do {
    ... read input ...

    try {
        number = std::stoi(s);
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR. The entered number must be an integer.\n";
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

**Solution two:**

If you just check `if (std::cin >> number)` (or in the condition of a loop) it'll fail if it couldn't read an int. No extra validation needed.

**Other points:**

- Use `\n` instead of `std::endl` unless you explicitly need to flush the stream (you don't)
- Never use `using namespace std`, even in short programs
- Check a bool using `myBool == false` is strange to read, prefer `!myBool`